# Typescript dynamic types declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to fix these errors and don't know how to do it. If you are an expert in the TS please help me with it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gWAFA3gLhgcgDc4AbAVwFMYBGfAGk2wCM8jTKYAmexmYPdFmwwA1q2LkqAZny8AvpjkBuTJigBPAA5UA8kwBWAFS1VkG7SABm8FRkyWyYYFACW4GA7ABBAE4+46gA8vADSMBQAHlAUYAAmEKIU6lYwekYmSInJ1mnG2nQwvAAi4VEx8akGeRQA2iEAupm5JnX1mAB8ABRwPgDmeHUFIkkpRfUAlKi8oJCw4BQAMoQkmXA1Pb01AAz19ba8APQHMACSEBAcAMQ00+DQMBAUM7FLK8jzr+t9NdS7ttgzCAgEgUAB0JBAvU6j2er3GtgUGE8vn86k6NXwwHoBBE+Am+wwRxgAHUQD4RAk4AlItpnBRYvZHCiAujMdj8Lj8apCcczhcqNdOIzvH4WRi4OzOfDMEA

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0UZb.png)

```
  const a = {
  a: 'value 1',
  b: 'value 2',
  c: {
    k: 'value 3'
  }
};

type ObjType = typeof a;

function funArray<
  K extends keyof ObjType = keyof ObjType, 
  D extends ObjType[K] = ObjType[K]
>(arg: [K, keyof D]) {
  const oneLvl = a[arg[0]];

  // Issue # 1
  // Type 'keyof D' cannot be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; c: { k: string; }; }[K]'.
  const secondLvl = oneLvl[arg[1]];
  console.log(secondLvl);
}
funArray(['c', 'k']);

// Works as expected
funArray(['c', 'k']);

// Issue # 2
// Type '"k"' is not assignable to type 'number | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | "toLowerCase" | ... 27 more ... | "padEnd"'.
funArray(['a', 'k']);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of second generic:

```js
const a = {
  a: 'value 1',
  b: 'value 2',
  c: {
    k: 'value 3'
  }
};

type ObjType = typeof a;

function funArray<
  K extends keyof ObjType,
  >(arg: [K, keyof ObjType[K]]) {
  const fst = arg[0];
  const scd = arg[1]
  const oneLvl = a[fst];


  const secondLvl = oneLvl[scd];
  console.log(secondLvl);
}

funArray(['c', 'k']);

// Works as expected
funArray(['c', 'k']);

// This error is expected, because `k` can be used as a key to a['a']
funArray(['a', 'k']);
```

There is no issue with third example. This error is expected

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gWAFA3gLhgcgDc4AbAVwFMYBGfAGk2wCM8jTKYAmexmYPdFmwwA1q2LkqAZny8AvpjkBuTJigBPAA5UA8kwBWAFS1VkG7SABm8FRkyWyYYFACW4GA7ABBAE4%2046gA8vADSMBQAHlAUYAAmEKIU6lYwekYmDEIAfAAUcD4A5ngA2iF0icnWacbapQC6dQCUqLygkLCW0EjwhcUADHW22G1dEMCx3fkFxdR1reBd4BQAMoQkk8WdUIOqdkIjsBAUbbGr68hLZ8VjsTv7CyAkFAB0JCAFOUcnZ422CnueXz%20dQ5Yr4YD0AgifBNWyYAD08JgAHUQD4RAk4AlItpnBRYvZHECAqDwZD8NDYbtETBDAALFzYvxomCM8IRXHRWLlJjHOBkI4wAAGIiFfDgYBgvJgAvx8ExFRgUBA8DBcBhhO8fhJavJlN%20mCAA)